# Why Is the DFT of a Signal Symmetric About Its Central Bin?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

When i take an N point DFT of a signal, it comes out to be conjugate symmetric about the point N/2 . Could someone please tell how to understand this intuitively or mathematically ?

Comment: lacks research. Wikipedia. DFT. Properties. The Real-input DFT. Anyway, if you need to prove that, just insert a real-valued signal into the DFT formula and show that symmetrical terms are conjugate to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is only conjugate symmetric if the input signal is Real Signal.

The reason for that is the DFT is built by [Complex Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) which can be decomposed into Sine and Cosine.
Since the Sine governs the Complex part and is $ N $ periodic one could see it creates conjugate symmetry of the DFT.

You just need to follow the definition of the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

Answer (score 1):

Given strictly real input, the DFT result components should sum to something that is strictly real.  If you have an FFT coefficient result with a non-zero imaginary component (representing a Sine), then the only way to get a real sum is to also have another coefficient of the same (aliased) frequency with the exact opposite (negated) non-zero imaginary component.

Thus the mirror symmetry must be conjugated.